# A question in hyperplane

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $E$ is a convex set in $R^n$, with nonempty interior, and $y$ is a boundary 
point of $E$. Why  there is a hyperplane $H$ such that $y \in H$ and $E$ lies entirely on 
one side of $H$?

- (Call a set $H \subseteq {R^n}$ a hyperplane if there exist real numbers ${a_1},....{a_n},c$ (with ${a_i} \ne 0$ for 
  at least one $i$) such that $H$ consists of all points $x=({x_1},....{x_n})$ that satisfy  $\sum\limits_{}^{} {{a_i}{x_i} = c} $)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn–Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem